# NodeJS Express - Difference between GET/POST/PATCH/DELETE behind the scenes

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios

Is `.get()` , `.post()`, `.put()` , `.delete()` purely semantic with nodeJS and express? *(behind the scenes are these methods any different?)*

If you're designing an API, at the end of the day you're just sending a `req` and awaiting a `res` payload

Can you for instance delete things off a database using a `.get()` request if you really wanted to?

Or accept a `req.body` using a `.get()` request?

What about frontend with axios?

Answer (score 2):

*[answer comes from a few senior devs, Andrew Studnicky and Gavin Ray]*

Yes you can delete items off a database using a `get()` request

HTTP verbs are GET/POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE/OPTIONS.
You design your API to match the semantics of the request but there is nothing FORCING you to

I would note that Axios (frontend) in particular has some rules around what can go into request types, especially when bending the rules of REST.  For example, a `DELETE` can *technically* have a request body (the REST whitepapers do not specify that it cannot) - and while it is not advised, some vendors (such as auth0) do require a requestBody on a `DELETE`

You should note that axios *will strip this out* before issuing the request, unless you perform some workaround logic

While you *can* theoretically do whatever you want with the data once your server gets it, your consumers and coworkers will appreciate if you stick to convention.

Community guidelines exist as a collective contribution of wisdom in design as much as they do in semantics.